# Finding symmetric difference with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, set-theory

I have two collections `a` and `b`. I would like to compute the set of items in either `a` or `b`, but not in both (a logical exclusive or). With LINQ, I can come up with this:

```
IEnumerable<T> Delta<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
{
    return a.Except (b).Union (b.Except (a));
}
```

I wonder if there are other more efficient or more compact ways of producing the difference between the two collections.

Edit 1: Jon Skeet posted a first solution which does not preserve the order of the items by relying on a `HashSet`. I wonder if there are other approaches which would preserve the order of `a` and `b` in the output.

Comment: What if a or b contain duplicates?

Comment: In my case, `a` and `b` do not contain duplicates, so this is not a concern for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `HashSet<T>` directly - it has a `SymmetricExceptWith` method:

```
HashSet<T> data = new HashSet<T>(a);
data.SymmetricExceptWith(b);
```

EDIT: If you want to maintain the order, here's an alternative:

```
HashSet<T> data = new HashSet<T>(a);
data.IntersectWith(b);
foreach (T t in a.Concat(b))
{
    if (!data.Contains(t))
    {
        yield return t;
    }
}
```

This has the following important differences:

- Both `a` and `b` are iterated over twice. In some cases that could be a very bad thing - you could call `ToList` on each of them to start with to retain a buffer.
- If there are duplicates in either `a` or `b`, they will be yielded multiple times. If you wanted to avoid this you could keep a set of already-yielded values. At this point, it would be equivalent to:

  ```
  a.Concat(b).Except(a.Intersect(b))
  ```

That's still only *two* set operations instead of the three in your original code though.

Comment: Thanks Jon for your quick reply. HashSet work fine as long as you are not interested in the original order of the items. What if I want to keep the order of the items in `a` and `b` in the difference?

Comment: @Pierre: I've edited my answer with another couple of options.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. In my case, `a` and `b` do not contain duplicates, so this is not a concern. The LINQ expression you propose is much more readable (and therefore maintainable) than the piece of code involving the `HashSet`. I like it!

Answer (score 6):

Given a.Except(b) and b.Except(a) are disjoint, you can use `concat` instead of `union`, saving a set operator (and `concat` is more efficient).

```
return a.Except (b).Concat (b.Except (a));
```

This still runs through each list twice.

Comment: Thank you; you are right, `Concat` will be faster than `Union` since my inputs are disjoint; I had overlooked that point.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar need for a project in my company, so we wrote this extension:

```
public class EnumerablePair<T> : IReadOnlyCollection<T>
{
    private IReadOnlyCollection<T> _Left;
    private IReadOnlyCollection<T> _Right;
    private IEnumerable<T> _Union;
    private int _Count;
    public EnumerablePair(IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right)
    {
        _Left = left?.ToList() ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>().ToList();
        _Right = right?.ToList() ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>().ToList();
        _Count = Left.Count + Right.Count;
        _Union = Left.Union(Right);
    }

    public int Count => _Count;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<T> Left { get => _Left; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<T> Right { get => _Right; }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _Union.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _Union.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExtension
{
    public static EnumerablePair<T> ExclusiveDisjunction<T>(this IEnumerable<T> leftOperand, IEnumerable<T> rightOperand, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        if (leftOperand == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(leftOperand), $"{nameof(leftOperand)} is null.");
        if (rightOperand == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rightOperand), $"{nameof(rightOperand)} is null.");

        // TODO : Can be optimized if one of the IEnumerable parameters is empty.

        bool leftIsBigger = leftOperand.Count() > rightOperand.Count();
        var biggestOperand = leftIsBigger ? leftOperand.ToList() : rightOperand.ToList();
        var smallestOperand = leftIsBigger ? rightOperand.ToList() : leftOperand.ToList();

        var except1 = biggestOperand.ToList();
        var except2 = Enumerable.Empty<T>().ToList();

        Func<T, T, bool> areEquals;
        if (comparer != null)
            areEquals = (one, theOther) => comparer.Equals(one, theOther);
        else
            areEquals = (one, theOther) => one?.Equals(theOther) ?? theOther == null;

        foreach (T t in smallestOperand)
            if (except1.RemoveAll(item => areEquals(item, t)) == 0)
                except2.Add(t);

        if (leftIsBigger)
            return new EnumerablePair<T>(except1, except2);
        return new EnumerablePair<T>(except2, except1);
    }
}
```

It compares elements of two collections (using an `IEqualityComparer` or not, at your choice).

- The returned object, an `EnumerablePair<T>`, contains objects that are in `leftOperand` or `rightOperand`, but not both (XOR).
- `EnumerablePair<T>.Left` contains objects that are in `leftOperand` but not in `rightOperand`.
- `EnumerablePair<T>.Right` contains objects that are in `rightOperand` but not in `leftOperand`.

You can use the extension like this :

```
var xorList = list1.ExclusiveDisjunction(list2);
var leftXor = xorList.Left;
var rightXor = xorList.Right;
```

`xorList`, `leftXor` and `rightXor` are `IEnumerable<T>`.