# How to create mutually exclusive properties in C#

Tags: c#

I have a class with three properties:

```
class PriceCondition
{
    public Product SalesCode {...}
    public ControlDate Condition {...}
    public PriceDetail Pricing {...}
}
```

Any instance of `PriceCondition` can only have EITHER a `SalesCode` or a `Condition`.  If `Condition` is chosen, then `Pricing` is required, but that's not pertinent to this discussion.

Being a relatively poor programmer, I initially tried the following:

```
    public Product SalesCode
    {
        get { return _salesCode; }
        set 
        {
            this.Condition = null;
            _salesCode = value; 
        }
    }

    public ControlDate Condition
    {
        get { return _cond; }
        set 
        {
            this.SalesCode = null;
            _cond = value; 
        }
    }
```

In hindsight, it's obvious why that created a stack overflow.  Searching for the right way, I found [this SO answer about XORing a `List`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198649/xor-of-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp), but I can't figure out how to apply that to what I'm trying to do, since `Except` is an `IEnumerable` method, and I'm not using a `List<T>` or anything similar.

How can I ensure that only one of the properties is set at any time?  Can I pass in a `var CodeOrCondition` as a parameter in the constructor, use `typeof` to figure out what it is, then assign it appropriately?  I only sort of understand what I just said, so having some foreknowledge of whether that's going to work or not would be helpful before I set out to write the code.

**Update:**

After excellent help found in the answer(s), I ended up with this:

```
public class PriceCondition
{
    #region Constructor
    /// <summary>Create an empty PriceCondition.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>An empty constructor is required for EntityFramework.</remarks>
    public PriceCondition();

    /// <summary>Create a PriceCondition that uses a Sales Code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="salesCode">The Product to use.</param>
    public PriceCondition(Product salesCode)
    {
        SalesCode = salesCode;
        Condition = null;
        Pricing = null;
    }

    /// <summary>Create a PriceCondition that uses a DateControl and Price (e.g. "0D7")
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dateControl">The DateControl Condition to use.</param>
    /// <param name="price">The PriceDetail to use.</param>
    public PriceCondition(Condition dateControl, PriceDetail price)
    {
        SalesCode = null;
        Condition = dateControl;
        Pricing = price;
    }
    #endregion
....
}
```

**Second Update:**

EntityFramework got in my way.  I knew that it required empty constructors, but didn't realize the depth of why.  We're finding that using `private set` is keeping EF from populating objects from the database.  At least that's what it looks like.  We're persisting the data in our **DBInitializer**, but the information isn't getting loaded into `PriceCondition` when we try to use it.  The easy answer seemed to be putting the setters back to a standard backing-store method and relying on the business logic layer to never set a `SalesCode` and a `ControlDate` on the same `PriceCondition`.  But now that's not working either.  We'll bang away at it more, but any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: why can't you just set the `_cond` and `_salesCode` fields directly in your property setters?

Comment: This seems like poor modeling. You should make two classes that inherit a common base, each containing only the properties they need. Use `is` or `as` to figure out which type it is then later.

Comment: Properties *usually* don't cause side effects like that. I would probably go with methods instead (`SetSalesCode`, `SetCondition`).

Comment: Don't use public property setters to enforce business logic. Seems like your class could be a simple immutable value object, with read-only fields/properties and mutation methods that are appropriately named and return a new modified immutable instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the backing variables instead of the properties:

```
public Product SalesCode
{
    get { return _salesCode; }
    set 
    {
        _cond = null;
        _salesCode = value; 
    }
}

public ControlDate Condition
{
    get { return _cond; }
    set 
    {
        _salesCode = null;
        _cond = value; 
    }
}
```

Another approach that I prefer personally is to make an immutable object, and provide constructors for the possible configurations:

```
class PriceCondition {

  public Product SalesCode { get; private set; }
  public ControlDate Condition { get; private set; }
  public PriceDetail Pricing { get; private set; }

  public PriceCondition(Product salesCode) {
    SalesCode = salesCode;
    Condition = null;
    Pricing = null;
  }

  public PriceCondition(ControlDate condition, PriceDetail pricing) {
    SalesCode = null;
    Condition = condition;
    Pricing = pricing;
  }

}
```

(You should validate the parameters in the constructors also, but this shows the principle.)

Comment: I went with the second approach.  Since I'm using EntityFramework, I also had to have a parameterless constructor, so I added that, then referred everything to backing store fields.  There's a little more work to do, but I'm underway.

Answer (score 0):

Just one small change to your attempt will prevent the stack overflow:

```
public Product SalesCode
{
    get { return _salesCode; }
    set 
    {
```

```
        if (value != null)
```

```
            this.Condition = null;
        _salesCode = value; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of something like this:

```
    public class PriceCondition
{
    private Product m_Product;
    private ControlDate m_ControlDate;

    public PriceCondition(Product product)
    {
        m_Product = product;
    }

    public PriceCondition(ControlDate controlDate)
    {
        m_ControlDate = controlDate;
    }

    public Product SalesCode
    {
        get { return m_product; }
    }

    public ControlDate Condition
    {
        get { return m_ControlDate; }
    }
}
```

The two constructors will always guarantee that one of the properties is not set (it's in fact null).
With the two read-only properties you can always see which one is set (and one of them will be set, because of the constructors)